# KDB+ / Q table creation with foreign key

Tags: database, foreign-keys, kdb, q-lang

My question is about creating a table with q and using foreign keys. I know how to do it the following way

```
q)T1:([id:1 2 3 4 5]d1:"acbde")
q)T2:([id:1 2 3 4 5]f1:`T1$2 2 2 4 4)
```

But now lets say I want to create the table with the `!` operator flipping a dictionary this way

```
q)T3:1!flip ((`id`f1 )!((1 2 3 4 5);(2 2 2 4 4)))
```

How can I set a foreign key to table T1s primary key with this way of creating a table.

**Update**

Well, I thought my upper example would be sufficient for myself to solve my actual problem, but unfortunately its not.

What if I have this lists of lists layout A and B

```
q)A:enlist 1 2 3 4 5
q)B:(enlist "abcde"), (enlist `v`w`x`y`z)
q)flip (`id`v1`v2)!(B,A)
```

How can I make the list A as foreign key to table T1?

**Update 2**

And how would I implement it if I have `A` coming from somewhere, not initializing it myself. Do I have to make a copy from the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same syntax on the column values list:

```
q)T3:1!flip ((`id`f1 )!((1 2 3 4 5);(`T1$2 2 2 4 4)))
q)T3~T2
1b
```

**Update:**

Again for this case we can use the same syntax on the list -

```
q)A:enlist`T1$1 2 3 4 5
q)meta flip (`id`v1`v2)!(B,A)
c | t f  a
--| ------
id| c
v1| s
v2| j T1
```

**Update2:**

Same syntax applied to the variable name:

```
q)A:1 2 3 4 5
q)meta flip (`id`v1`v2)!(B,enlist`T1$A)
c | t f  a
--| ------
id| c
v1| s
v2| j T1
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but i was not able to fix my actual problem. I updated my question

Comment: well @jgleeson ... update2 -> with ```A``` give like this ```q)A:enlist`T1$1 2 3 4 5``` is the only way then to do ```q)flip (`id`v1`v2)!(B,enlist`T1$A[0])``` ?

Comment: If A is that format, you can use the syntax in Update1 - 
`flip (\`id\`v1\`v2)!(B,A)`.